# How to find the range and inverse of this linear operator?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, integration, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Given $T \colon C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ defined by $$Tx(t):= \int_0^t x(r) dr$$ for each $t\in [0,1]$, where $C[0,1]$ is the normed space of continuous real-valued (or complex-valued) functions defined on the closed interval $[0,1]$ with the norm given by $||x|| \colon= \max_{t \in [0,1]} |x(t)|$.

How to find the range of this operator?

This operator is one-to-one; so an inverse exists. How to find this inverse?

Comment: The range seems to be the set of all differentiable functions which are zero at zero. if I'm right. It is one to one, inverse is obtained by differentiating.

Comment: Note that $Tx (0) = 0$ for all $x$, hence it cannot have an inverse. If $Tx=y$, then $\dot{y} = x$, $y(0) =0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $Tx=y$, we have:
$$y(t)=(Tx)(t)= \int_0^t x(r) dr$$
Since $x$ is continuous, $y$ is differentiable and we have:
$$x=y'$$
So
$$T^{-1}(y)=y'$$

About range of $T$, it's clear that each $Tx$ is differentiable and
$$(Tx)(0)=0$$
Let $y\in C[0,1]$ be a differentiable function such that
$$y(0)=0$$
we have:
$$(Ty')(t)=\int_0^t y'(r) dr=y(t)$$
provided this integral exists. So which integral do you use? e.g if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300537/defining-definite-integral-using-indefinite-integral) definition is used then the integral always exists and the range of $T$ is all differentiable functions that are 0 at 0. 
About Riemann integration I think the range is more limited.

Comment: Why should this Riemann integral should not exist? I reckon it is equal to $y(t)-y(0)=y(t)-0=y(t)$. What can possibly go wrong, I wonder?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: It doesn't exist always for derivatives.

Comment: The range is functions which are continuously differentiable (differentiable with continuous derivative) and which are zero at zero. Not just differentiable. Then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus does it for you.